# Scope all ActiveAdmin to resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm using Rails 4 and activeadmin master branch on commit fea5d43fd438.

Currently, I'm having urls like this:

```
localhost:3000/admin/posts
```

I'm working on scoping all my resources into another resource (let's say, scoping posts to a blog), so my routes would look like:

```
localhost:3000/my-first-blog/admin/posts
```

or

```
localhost:3000/admin/my-first-blog/posts
```

Both are good, although the first one is preferred.

I could not find a way to achieve this using ActiveAdmin. I tried modifying my routes file to this:

```
Confly::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :blogs, path: '/', do
    ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  end
end
```

But ActiveAdmin started complaining about missing path methods. I also tried setting a default namespace on the ActiveAdmin initializer, but it didn't work neither.

Any idea? :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it using the `belongs_to` feature:

http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#belongs_to